# print_tx TXID doesn't print ring

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-forks

Using the cli wallet, I swept my (pre-MoneroV fork) xmr to a new address using segregate-pre-fork-outputs appended to the command.
Then in the daemon I typed print_tx xxxxxxx where xxxxxx is the txid of the transaction.
The daemon only prints the block height.  Not the ring.  Is segregate-pre-fork-outputs only set up to work with the transfer command and not the sweep_all command?  If so, I can't use the print_tx command to show the ring.
However, I copied and saved all the text printed out during the sweep_all command in the wallet.  It shows 8 inputs, each with 6 block heights, and an asterisk next to one of the blocks for each input.  Is there some way to use that information to determine the ring for a MoneroV transaction?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax changed recently, and you have to add "+json" to get what you need:

print_tx TXID +json

The reason was that this could be pretty spammy, so is not disabled by default.